# Multiple inputs for coxph

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression

Is there a way to run coxph for multiple inputs. Here I have used the input `hsa_let_7b_5p`.

```
coxph(Surv(Time, Status)~ hsa_let_7b_5p,  data=as.data.frame(test))


Call:
    coxph(formula = Surv(Time, Status) ~ hsa_let_7b_5p, data = as.data.frame(test))


                   coef exp(coef) se(coef)    z    p
    hsa_let_7b_5p 0.169     1.184    0.173 0.98 0.33

    Likelihood ratio test=0.94  on 1 df, p=0.333
    n= 91, number of events= 45
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear to me if this answers the question you meant or the question you asked, but you can add more regression variables to the right side of the formula (after the ~)

```
coxph(Surv(Time, Status)~ hsa_let_7b_5p + x + y,  data=as.data.frame(test))
```

where x & y are the names of other variables (columns) in your data frame.

You may wish to read into interactions and stratification at some point